# Svcutil Configuration files are not supported.net core

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, svcutil.exe

I am using `svcutil` to get wcf service into my project.

But i get error while trying to initialize the soapClient:

`ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient();`

**Here is the error:**

> Configuration files are not supported

I use this command to get it to my project:

`svcutil myUrl.asmx /out:name.cs/config:name.config`

I copied all the generated config content into my web.config file.

But without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **.net core** i had to use `dotnet svcutil` and NOT just `svcutil`.

In cmd I use:
`dotnet svcutil myUrl.admx`

For making it sync(as default it rendered as async) use:

`dotnet svcutil myUrl.admx --sync`

Now. You can wrap the rendered reference.cv with your namespace if you want.

Answer (score 0):

WCF proxies generated by svcutil do not support loading from separate configuration files or System.Configuration.Configuration objects.

You can add a wcf service reference using [the WCF Web Service Reference Provider tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide).

Currently because wcf is not ported to .net core. Microsoft recommends using [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/why-migrate-wcf-to-dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-6.0) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely will check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2022, you have to download the tool.

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil`

Then, run command

`dotnet-svcutil <WCF-WEB-URL>`