# Add WCF Service Reference to Visual Studio 2022 Project with Client Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2022, client-certificates

I am attempting to add a WCF Web Service reference to a C# project where the WSDL is secured behind a client certificate.  I have successfully added the certificate to SOAPUI and made calls just fine, but when I attempt to add the reference in Visual Studio, I dont get prompted to select the certificate.

How do I add a WCF Service endpoint which requires a client certificate in Visual Studio 2022 Community?

Comment: If you added the certificate via SOAP UI, are you able to download the WSDL and save it to disk ? If so, you can perform an _Add Service Reference_ from Visual Studio, then Browse for the WSDL.

Comment: Yes, I can even see it in IE and download it.  However, it looks like it's importing another file which I cannot get, so I got errors when trying to do it via file..

Answer (score 0):

Specify the client certificate using endpoint behavior like below:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<behaviors>  
  <endpointBehaviors>  
    <behavior name="endpointCredentialsBehavior">  
      <clientCredentials>  
        <clientCertificate findValue="Cohowinery.com"
           storeLocation="LocalMachine"  
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />  
      </clientCredentials>  
    </behavior>  
  </endpointBehaviors>  
</behaviors>
<bindings>  
  <wsHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" >  
      <security mode="Message">  
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
      </security>  
    </binding>  
  </wsHttpBinding>  
</bindings>  
<client>  
  <endpoint address="http://machineName/Calculator"
            behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialsBehavior"  
            binding="wsHttpBinding"  
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"  
            contract="ICalculator"  
            name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator">   
  </endpoint>  
</client>
```

For more information, check out [Message Security with a Certificate Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client) or [Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication).

Comment: Assuming this is not a .net core project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464797/svcutil-configuration-files-are-not-supported-net-core