# error: PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported or How .NET Core 6 consume SOAP .NET Framework wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, soap, .net-4.8

I have Dot Net Framework 3.5 Web Service: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
I want to consume it on dot Net Core (3 or 6, any version).

When I run the program, it throws exception:
PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported

Is it technically possible or not to call WCF Dot Net Framework 3.5 from any Dot Net Core application?

Reference:
https://medium.com/compendium/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb
https://howtodomssqlcsharpexcelaccess.blogspot.com/2019/06/mvc-consume-web-service-service.html

Comment: Option 1 (best): migrate away from WCF (the whole WS-* approach is old and now recognised as a dead end: RESTful APIs are the current practice). Option 2 (in the meantime): look at CoreWCF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Svcutil Configuration files are not supported.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464797/svcutil-configuration-files-are-not-supported-net-core)

Comment: Thank you Richard for your input! Could I just know is it technically possible or not to call Dot Net Framework 3.5 from any Dot Net Core application?

Comment: Hi Tom, I looked to your link, thank you! I dont really understand the part:  wcf is not ported to .net core. Microsoft recommends using gRPC instead.

Comment: notice CoreWCF is the server and not the client, if you want to have a client library https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

Comment: are you sure you have wcf? because you talk about webservice, aswell - those arent the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service

Comment: Thank you Rand Random for your comment, that is a good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mentor gave me [an article](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/consuming-soap-apis-in-dotnet-core) that provided the answer. Mister Khalidabuhakmeh does a great job explaining how to consume SOAP APIs in .NET Core; thank you!

To summarize their steps:

1. Check if you installed .NET Core 2.1; if not, [download from Microsoft and install](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.1).
2. Open Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2022.

   - Create a .NET Core Console App.
   - Go to View, then click Terminal.
   - At the terminal, input:

     ```
     dotnet new tool-manifest
     ```
3. At the Terminal, input:

   ```
   dotnet tool install dotnet-svcutil
   ```
4. At the Terminal, input:

   ```
   dotnet dotnet-svcutil https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso
   ```

**If you have synchronous operations and you do have synchronous operations, then:**

4. At Terminal input: **--sync**

   ```
   dotnet dotnet-svcutil https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso --sync
   ```

   [More information](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/dotnet-svcutil-notes.md)

   **or**

   Input the other WSDL link:

   ```
   dotnet dotnet-svcutil <wsdl url>
   ```
5. Consume SOAP:

   ```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
    var client = new TextCasingSoapTypeClient(
        TextCasingSoapTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.TextCasingSoap,
        "https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso");

    var result =
        await client.AllLowercaseWithTokenAsync("THIS IS A STRING", "");

    // result: this is a string
    var value = result.Body.AllLowercaseWithTokenResult;

    Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx.
How I solve it was by adding to the constructor

```
CalculatorSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap
```

or

```
CalculatorSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap12
```

i.e.

```
public static int add(int x, int y){
    CalculatorSoapClient client = new CalculatorSoapClient(CalculatorSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap);
    return client.Add(x, y);
}
```

I should add that I didn't edit `Reference.cs` as suggested in [here](https://medium.com/compendium/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb)!

Answer (score 0):

in addition to already provided useful answers/comments, this works just as well:

```
string remoteAddress = "http://localhost:44467/WebService1.asmx";
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(remoteAddress);

using (var service1 = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient(binding, endpointAddress))
{
    var sr = await service1.AAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

there was no need to run svcutil, vs2022 added reference.cs